# Div - CSS Moving Problem

Tags: css, html

I got a problem..

Just imagine, that I got 6 divs in THIS order:

```
DIV1,DIV2,DIV3,
DIV4,DIV5,DIV6
```

so.. I built a Jquery script, which allows me, to move one of the Divs away.. 
example: 
I can move DIV2 away and then it looks like this:

```
DIV1,DIV3,DIV4               DIV2 (anywhere out)
DIV5,DIV6
```

and this is my problem.. I dont want, that all divs move one up, I would like something like this:

```
DIV1,    ,DIV3               DIV2 (anywhere out)
DIV4,DIV5,DIV6
```

the css of one Div:

```
float:left;
height:20px;
width:20px; 
border:1px solid white;
position: absolute;

background-color:Gray;
border: 1px solid WHite;
```

hope u guys can help me :(

Comment: to help me, the script isn't necessary.. it just moves me the clicked div from its coordinates (X,Y) to a defined place (X,Y)

Comment: What about replacing that div with another, blank div of the same size? Or just duplicating it on other place and hide the original with css, but leave it in place? OR you can make each div a wrapper that stays in place to keep that place. Just suggestions... it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to dynamically set the `top` and `left` properties of each `.box`:

http://jsfiddle.net/nSdpe/

```
$('.box').each(function() {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $(this).css({
        top: pos.top,
        left: pos.left
    });
}).css({
    position: 'absolute'
});
```

Comment: thx 4 your answer.. but I create 1000 Div's/Boxes for my Application.. I can't create 1000 of these functions, where I set 1000 times manually the top/left properties..

Comment: You don't have to make "1000 functions". This handles every single `.box`. I've updated my demo to be more obvious, try clicking on a `.box`.

Comment: i click on a .box and nothing happens.. Like last time.. but there is also a difference.. in your example.. he defines the new pos permamently, the Div ISNT moving, just teleporting, mine moves

Comment: ok worked now fine.. I justed put your code in a function and called it on a mouseover.. have to find now a gut event to call it, but It works :D

Comment: The movement in my demo was "for demonstration purposes only", I wasn't trying to make it like yours :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this working the way you'd like I think you'd have to position each box absolutely with a fixed position.

So each box would have to have something like:

```
#Box1{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}

#Box2{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:150px;
}
```

Another option would be to have each of the 4 boxes inside a container that doesn't move. I'll put together a quick demo.

**UPDATE**

Here's a demo of using a container div to keep the position: http://jsfiddle.net/fv2WQ/

Comment: thx 4 your answer! I create these divs Dynamically.. So I can give each one this class (with position:absolute) but then, all the divs will be on the same place.. Up in the left corner of the window :(

Comment: Notice that I set the position of top and left for the 2 examples above. This is what puts the divs into position. Each div would have to have a unique Id.

Comment: each div has got an unique id.. I'm creating 1000 divs for my Application.. the id is the number.. div1.ID = 1 and so on.. But I cant create now 1000 classes foreach div/box :(

Comment: O_O ... dude... @eMi, use classes for styling.  Using ids for styling 1000 elements is insane!

Comment: See my update eMi. With 1000 div's it doesn't sound feasible to do what I first sugested. You did origionally say 6 divs :P

Comment: Like i told, I gave all 1000 divs one class.. and the property: position:absolute.. each div will be placed in the left up corner of the window..

Comment: I know. Did you see the demo I created for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the divs in a wrapper which would serve as a placeholder.

```
.wrapper{
float:left;
height:20px;
width:20px; 
padding:0px;
}

.content{
height:20px;
width:20px; 
border:1px solid white;
position: absolute;
background-color:Gray;
}
```

and then just place content in the wrapper

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

But yeah, without more code it's hard to tell what will work and what won't.